# The method show in DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
.
.
.
    public  void show_read_menu(Bundle args){

        Menux editNameDialog = new Menux();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
        editNameDialog.setArguments(args);
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");

    }
.
.
   public static class Menux extends DialogFragment {
   //nested class
```

Unable to call the DialogFragment from the main ActionBarActivity class as above getting error on the .show() method :**The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)**

Comment: Which part is confusing you? The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. The `show()` method can't take the parameters you have provided.

Comment: trivial import issue.

Comment: your imports should be from the support library

Comment: I just switched to ActionBarActivity from Activity ... to use appcompat and imported **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;**. I did not encounter the error while using Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for some completeness.
It seems it was a trivial import issue, Since I was switching from **Activity** to **ActionBarActivity** the previous import were causing the issue.

Problem was caused by below imports.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Solved the issue by replacing them with...

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
```